# ggplot scale_x_date date_breaks argument not recognized

Tags: r, ggplot2

It doesn't seem to work as documented... Any idea?

```
x <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("2015-12-01", "2015-12-03", "2015-12-15", "2015-12-28")), N=c(1,3,2,4))
ggplot(x, aes(date, N)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 day")
Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "date", identity, breaks = breaks,  : 
  unused argument (date_breaks = "1 day")
```

Comment: see `?scale_x_date`. It appears that `date_breaks` is deprecated and you should use `(breaks= "1 day")`. This works for me

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented:

```
library(ggplot2)
last_month <- Sys.Date() - 0:29
df <- data.frame(
    date = last_month,
    price = runif(30)
)
base <- ggplot(df, aes(date, price)) +
    geom_line()

base + scale_x_date(breaks = "1 day")
```

using your data:

```
ggplot(x, aes(date, N)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_x_date(breaks="1 day")
```

[image]